# for(i=0;i<number;i++) loop behavior not working as expected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

The code below is SUPPOSED to do this: Wherever current athlete is, when you tap a next button the code below is executed. It should change current athlete to the next athlete in the array, then when it gets to the last person, it needs to circle back to 0 (the first object). and it does do that perfectly. when I reach the end of the array though, it will go to the first person again, which is correct, but from then on will skip the last object in the array. any idea why?

```
 -(void)nextAthlete{

    NSUInteger index = [_athleteArray indexOfObject:_currentAthlete];

    Athlete *count = _athleteArray[index];

    NSLog(@"Current Athlete:%@ Index: %lu",count,(unsigned long)index);

    if(index < ((_athleteArray.count)-1)){
        index++;
        _currentAthlete = _athleteArray[index];
        _evalSelected = [self getMostRecentEval];
        [self updateInformation];
        NSLog(@"Index after being smaller than the array count: %lu",(unsigned long)index);
    }
    if(index == ((_athleteArray.count)-1)){
        _currentAthlete = _athleteArray[index];
            _evalSelected = [self getMostRecentEval];
            [self updateInformation];
        index=0;
        _currentAthlete = _athleteArray[index];
            NSLog(@"Index after being equal to array count: %lu",(unsigned long)index);
    }
    if(index > ((_athleteArray.count)-1)){
        index=0;
        _currentAthlete = _athleteArray[index];
    }
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Evaluation",_evalSelected.whosEval.full];


}
```

Comment: When you set `index=0`, you need to do it *before* doing anything else. Currently, when `index == _athleteArray.count`, you access the array before updating the index, which causes the out-of-bound access.

Comment: @Mac: I dont _want_ index to be zero. It needs to start with where ever the current athlete is. e.g. if I begin with athlete at position 3 out of 5, it needs to go to 4, then 5, then 0.

Comment: Is `index` declared inside or outside the loop?

Comment: @CarlVeazey:index is outside of the loop

Comment: @JosueEspinosa Hm... there's no loop in the method that `index` is declared in, so your statement contradicts your code - but I think I see what's happening. Are you doing something like `for (int i = 0; i < [_athleteArray count]; i++) { [self nextAthlete]; }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all those `if` statements. You're wrapping `nextIndex` around with the modulo operator so you don't need to apply all this other logic - setting `index` to `nextIndex` should suffice. Also, since they aren't if..else statements, you're incrementing and wrapping the index multiple times in the case of the second to last item in the array. When the second if block executes, so will the third, and so `_currentAthlete` will skip the last item in this situation.

Anyways, no need to repeat all that logic - make your code something like this:

```
NSUInteger nextIndex = (index + 1) % _athleteArray.count;

Athlete *count = _athleteArray[index];
NSLog(@"Current Athlete:%@ Index: %lu",count,(unsigned long)index);
index=nextIndex;
_currentAthlete = _athleteArray[index];
_evalSelected = [self getMostRecentEval];
[self updateInformation];
self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Evaluation",_evalSelected.whosEval.full];
```

This is kind of weird, though, because you skip the first value of `_selectedAthlete`. But I suppose you come back to it on the last iteration through the loop.

Comment: Yep. Thank you, didn't occur to me as I was originally using index++ so I just substituted. Thanks, works like a charm!

Comment: Yep, no problem. Always a good idea to step through something like this line by line in the debugger, as you would have then caught the double incrementing of `_currentAthlete`, probably much quicker than I figured it out by reading the code!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(index < _athleteArray.count)
```

needs to be

```
if(index < _athleteArray.count - 1).
```

Think about it -- if you have 4 athletes in your array, then when index = 3, you will enter the if clause and increment index to 4.

When you execute 
    `_currentAthlete = _athleteArray[index]` with index = 4, you get the error.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you, i'll accept your answer after the time counter has passed.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't crash anymore, but it still won't go past the last person, when I hit next it just stays. I change all the if statements with the extra count-1. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa, what do you want it to do after you display the last athlete? Got to the first one?

Comment: It should do the following: 0,1,2[continue adding 1],lastObject,0,1,2,....,lastObject...

Answer (score 1):

From your comment "if I begin with athlete at position 3 out of 5, it needs to go to 4, then 5, then 0" it sounds like you wish to advance to the next index treating the array as circular. To do this you can use the modulus operator, `%`, which for positive numbers is the *remainder*:

```
NSUInteger index = [_athleteArray indexOfObject:_currentAthlete];
NSUInteger nextIndex = (index + 1) % _athleteArray.count;
```

In your case you have 4 athletes so `index` will be in the range 0 -> 3.
Therefore `(index + 1)` is in the range 1 -> 4.
Taking the *remainder* after dividing by 4 gives 1, 2, 3, 0 respectively.
So `nextIndex` is the "following" index in a circular manner.